# AWS Amplify (AppSync + Cognito) Authorization using dynamic groups per organitzation/tenant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, graphql-schema

I have an AWS Amplify application that has a structure with multi-organizations:

Organization A -> Content of Organization A
Organization B -> Content of Organization B

Let's say we have the user Alice, Alice belongs to both organizations, however, she has different roles in each one, on organization A Alice is an administrator and has more privileges (i.e: can delete content or modify other's content), while on Organization B she is a regular user.

For this reason I cannot simply set regular groups on Amplify (Cognito), because some users, like Alice, can belong to different groups on different organizations.

One solution that I thought was having a group for each combination of organization and role.
i.e: `OrganizationA__ADMIN`, `OrganizationB__USER`, etc
So I could restrict the access on the schema using a group auth directive on the `Content` model:

`{allow: group, groupsField: "group", operations: [update]},`

The content would have a `group` field with a value: `OrganizationA__ADMIN`

Then I could add the user to the group using the [Admin Queries API](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin#enable-admin-queries)
However, it doesn't seem to be possible to add a user to a group dynamically, I'd have to manually create each group every time a new organization is created, which pretty much kills my idea.

Any other idea on how I can achieve the result I'm aiming for?
I know that I can add the restriction on code, but this is less safe, and I'd rather to have this constraint on the database layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into generating additional claims in you [pre-token-generation handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-token-generation-example-1)

Basically you can create an attribute that includes organization role mapping

e.g.

```json
{
// ...
  "custom:orgmapping": "OrgA:User,OrgB:Admin"
}
```

then transform them in your pre-token-generation handler into "pseudo" groups that don't actually exist in the pool.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and I'll update it here

Comment: @dfranca Did this work for you? What did your final solution look like? I have a very similar case and would love to know how you tackled this.

Comment: @Etep Yes, I have added a edit_groups on my schema that uses the combination of OrgA:ROLE, then I have created a custom pre token generation handler to add the claim with the user Org:Role combination